# LSTM for multidimensional data

Tags: rnn

Is there any ML framework that readily supports LSTM for multi-dimentionsal data ?

Best would be in Pytorch. But I don't think the official API supports it and I have found an implementation.

Comment: What's multi-dimensional? What's your loss function in this case? What are you trying to do?

Comment: In most example, the input to LSTM is a 1d array where each entry is a scalar. I'm trying to input into LSTM an 1d array where each entry is a 2d array.

Comment: @QuanVuong: You can just flatten the 2d array of each entry. Unless you want to process it with something that uses the 2d structure, such as a CNN? In which case you will want to figure out a RNN/CNN hybrid - the  way to do this that I have seen, in e.g. video classifier - is to have CNN layers first and RNN replacing fully-connected layer. There are no doubt other architectures. Explaining more about your data and goal should get you a more specific answer.

Comment: here is a good implementation in tensorflow [tf-mdlstm](https://github.com/philipperemy/tensorflow-multi-dimensional-lstm)